# Loop through a few commands using a function

Tags: python, pandas

I have a loop where I constantly got an error message.

```
print(((df1['col1_df'] == 0) & (df1['col2_df'] == True)).sum())
print(((df1['col1_df'] == 0) & (df1['col3_df'] == True)).sum())
print(((df1['col1_df'] == 0) & (df1['col4_df'] == True)).sum())
print(((df1['col1_df'] == 0) & (df1['col5_df'] == True)).sum())

print(((df2['col1_df'] == 0) & (df2['col2_df'] == True)).sum())
print(((df2['col1_df'] == 0) & (df2['col3_df'] == True)).sum())
print(((df2['col1_df'] == 0) & (df2['col4_df'] == True)).sum())
print(((df2['col1_df'] == 0) & (df2['col5_df'] == True)).sum())
```

I want to loop them through a function.

So far I have:

```
for i in range (2,5):
    col = "col{}_df".format(i)
    print(((df['col'] == 0) & (df['col'] == 2)).sum())
```

How can I number the df and let the df go through 1, 2, 3, 4 (like df1, df2 df3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`col` is a variable. `'col'` is a string. Having `df['col']` doesn't refer to the variable `col`.

Your string format is done wrong: `col = "col{}_df".format(i)`

Also, `range(2,5)` will give you `[2,5)` not `[2,5]`. It is not inclusive.

Answer (score 0):

You can express your entire code in two lines using a comprehension:

```
print(*( ((df1[f'col1_df'] == 0) & (df1[f'col{i}_df'] == True)).sum() for i in range(2,6) ), sep="\n")
print(*( ((df2[f'col1_df'] == 0) & (df2[f'col{i}_df'] == True)).sum() for i in range(2,6) ), sep="\n")
```

The expression `((df1[f'col1_df'] == 0) & (df1[f'col{i}_df'] == True)).sum() for i in range(2,6) )` creates a generator object yielding the 4 expressions one by one.

The `*` scatters the elements in this generator and passes the arguments to `print` as you would have passed a comma-separated argument list. The `end=\n` ensures that each of these arguments are separated by a new line when output.